# I am trying to create a file via a button press but i keep running into an error

Tags: java, android

I am creating a checkbook and am unable to create a file to write to for each separate account. When I try to create the file I get the error "unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown". I try to declare that my action listener method throws an exception but that makes the action listener method no longer able to work. I then tried to create a separate method that creates the file and is called by the button press but i still run into the same error

Here is my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    ...

    if (e.getSource() == create)  {
         creatNewAccount(name3.getText());
         BALANCE = Double.parseDouble(name2.getText());
    }
}
public void creatNewAccount(String s) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(s + ".txt", false);
}
```

Comment: It's a checked exception. `try`-`catch` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`creatNewAccount` is declared as possibly throwing an `IOException`. `IOException` is not a `RuntimeException`, so you must catch it.

```
if (e.getSource() == create)  {
     try {
         creatNewAccount(name3.getText());
     } catch (IOException ie) {
         ie.printStackTrace();
         // handle error
     }
     BALANCE = Double.parseDouble(name2.getText());
}
```

For more information, please read about [The Catch or Specify Requirement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) and [Catching and Handling Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).

---

A few other things I noticed:
 - The word you're looking for is *create*, not *creat*.
 - You're assigning something to `BALANCE`. Uppercase names are generally reserved for constants. Consider renaming this variable `balance`.
 - Consider more descriptive names for your text fields. `name2` and `name3` don't really say much.

Comment: What does ie.printStackTrace() mean? Thanks for the extra tips!!

Comment: `printStackTrace` will print a [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) of the exception. A stack trace basically shows what method called what method (it *traces* back through the *stack* of method calls) so you can start debugging.

Comment: I decided to eliminate the method and just create the file in the if statement of my action listener method. Should i still keep the printStackTrace() line?

Comment: Yes. This will help you debug.

Answer (score 2):

`IOException` is a checked exception. Given that you're calling it within an `ActionListener`, rethrowing the exception is not an option so you need to catch it.

```
try {
   creatNewAccount(name3.getText());
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   // more exception handling
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `actionPerformed()` you need to put a try/catch block around the `createNewAccount` call.  What you do with the exception once caught is up to you -- an easy thing to do is to wrap it in a `RuntimeException` which does not need to be caught (but might foul up your process until you do something more elaborate).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    ...

    if (e.getSource() == create)  {
         try {
             creatNewAccount(name3.getText());
         } catch( IOException ioe) {
             System.err.println("Whoops! " + ioe.getMessage());
             throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected exception", ioe);
         }
         BALANCE = Double.parseDouble(name2.getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you'll just need to catch the exception inside the method:

```
public void creatNewAccount(String s) {
    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(s + ".txt", false);
    } catch (IOException e){
        //TODO something to handle the error
    }
}
```